# Program to calculate smallest number with permutations divisible by a set of numbers

Tags: performance, c, integer

(**EDIT**: [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107687/program-to-test-for-divisibility-of-numbers) is the follow up question)

I have written a small program in C to calculate the smallest number where any of its permutations or the number itself is divisible by a set of given numbers. It works great when the number is only 4-5 digits but then it becomes very slow. Do you have any suggestions on optimizations when it comes to speed (or any optimization really)?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(char *, char *);
int icontains(int *, int, int);
int contains(char **, int, char *);
void permute(char **, char *, int, int, int *);
unsigned int factorial(unsigned int);

int main() {
  unsigned int i, j, k, l, m, n, len;
  char num_ints[10];
  char input[128];
  char str[7];
  char **family;
  char **ints;
  char *pch;
  unsigned int *flags;
  fgets(num_ints, 10, stdin);
  fgets(input, 128, stdin);
  len = strlen(input);
  pch = strtok(input," ");
  ints = calloc(atoi(num_ints), sizeof(char*));
  flags = calloc(atoi(num_ints),sizeof(unsigned int));
  for(i=0;i<atoi(num_ints);i++) {
    ints[i] = malloc(strlen(pch)+1);
    strcpy(ints[i], pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  for(k=1;;k++) {
    snprintf(str, 6, "%d", k);
    l = 0;
    n = strlen(str);
    len = factorial(n);
    family = calloc(len, sizeof(char*));
    if(n>=2) {
      permute(family, str, 0, n-1, &len);
    }else {
      family[0] = malloc(n+1);
      strcpy(family[0], str);
    }
    for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
      for(j=0;j<atoi(num_ints);j++) {
        if(atoi(family[i]) % atoi(ints[j]) == 0) {
          if(!icontains(flags, l+1, atoi(ints[j]))) {
            flags[l++] = atoi(ints[j]);
            if(l>=atoi(num_ints)) goto done;
          }
          continue;
        }
      }
    }
    for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
      free(family[i]);
    }
    free(family);
  }
  done:
  fprintf(stdout,"%d\n",k);
  for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
    free(family[i]);
  }
  free(family);
  for(i=0;i<atoi(num_ints);i++) {
    free(ints[i]);
  }
  free(ints);
  free(flags);
}

void swap(char *x, char *y) {
  char temp;
  temp = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = temp;
}

int icontains(int *array, int len, int a) {
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
    if(array[i]==a) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int contains(char **array, int len, char *a) {
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<len;++i) {
    if(!array[i] || !strcmp(array[i], a)) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

void permute(char **result, char *a, int l, int r, int *len) {
  int i;
  if(l==0) *len = 0;
  if(l == r) {
    if(a[0] == '0') return;
    if(!contains(result, *len, a)) {
      result[*len] = malloc(strlen(a)+1);
      strcpy(result[(*len)++], a);
    }
  }else {
    for(i=l;i<=r;i++) {
      swap((a+l), (a+i));
      permute(result, a, l+1, r, len);
      swap((a+l), (a+i)); //backtrack
    }
  }
}

unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n) {
  if(n==0)
    return 1;
  else
    return(n*factorial(n-1));
}
```

I compile it with gcc 5.2.0 with the following flags

```
-g -O2 -std=gnu99 -static -lm
```

Here are two sample input respectively outputs

Input:

```
5
3 5 7 9 11
```

Output:

```
459
```

Input:

```
7
164 278 293 382 483 598 23
```

Output:

```
102246
```

(**EDIT:** Here is my faster version, however it is still quite slow if you run it on my second example of input:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(char *, char *);
int icontains(int *, int, int);
void permute(unsigned int **, char *, int, int, int *);

int main() {
  unsigned int i, j, k, l, m, n, len, nints;
  char num_ints[10];
  char input[128];
  char str[10];
  char *pch;
  unsigned int *flags, *ints, *family;
  fgets(num_ints, 10, stdin);
  fgets(input, 128, stdin);
  nints = atoi(num_ints);
  len = strlen(input);
  pch = strtok(input," ");
  ints = calloc(nints, sizeof(ints));
  flags = calloc(nints, sizeof(flags));
  family = calloc(10, sizeof(family));
  for(i=0;i<nints;i++) {
    ints[i] = atoi(pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  for(k=1;;k++) {
    snprintf(str, 10, "%d", k);
    l = 0;
    n = strlen(str);
    len = 1;
    if(n>=2) {
      permute(&family, str, 0, n-1, &len);
    }else {
      family[0] = k;
    }
    for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
      for(j=0;j<nints;j++) {
        if(family[i] % ints[j] == 0) {
          if(!icontains(flags, l+1, ints[j])) {
            flags[l++] = ints[j];
            if(l>=nints) goto done;
          }
          continue;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  done:
  fprintf(stdout,"%d\n",k);
  free(family);
  free(ints);
  free(flags);
}

void swap(char *x, char *y) {
  char temp;
  temp = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = temp;
}

int icontains(int *array, int len, int a) {
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
    if(array[i]==a) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

void permute(unsigned int **result, char *a, int l, int r, int *len) {
  static int buflen = 10;
  int *new_result;
  int i, aint;
  if(l == 0) *len = 0;
  if(l == r) {
    if(a[0] == '0') return;
    aint = atoi(a);
    if(!icontains(*result, *len, aint)) {
      if(*len > buflen) {
        buflen = *len;
        new_result = realloc(*result, buflen * sizeof(*result));
        if(new_result != NULL) {
          *result = new_result;
        }else {
          fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't allocate memory for buffer.");
        }
      }
      (*result)[(*len)++] = aint;
    }
  }else {
    for(i=l;i<=r;i++) {
      swap((a+l), (a+i));
      permute(result, a, l+1, r, len);
      swap((a+l), (a+i)); //backtrack
    }
  }
}
```

)

(**EDIT2:** I realized I don't how to check for duplicates of permutations because that is slow. Here is the even faster version:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(char *, char *);
int icontains(int *, int, int);
void permute(unsigned int **, char *, int, int, int *);

int main() {
  unsigned int i, j, k, l, m, n, len, nints;
  char num_ints[10];
  char input[128];
  char str[10];
  char *pch;
  unsigned int *flags, *ints, *family;
  fgets(num_ints, 10, stdin);
  fgets(input, 128, stdin);
  nints = atoi(num_ints);
  len = strlen(input);
  pch = strtok(input," ");
  ints = calloc(nints, sizeof(ints));
  flags = calloc(nints, sizeof(flags));
  family = calloc(10, sizeof(family));
  for(i=0;i<nints;i++) {
    ints[i] = atoi(pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  for(k=1;;k++) {
    snprintf(str, 10, "%d", k);
    l = 0;
    n = strlen(str);
    len = 1;
    if(n>=2) {
      permute(&family, str, 0, n-1, &len);
    }else {
      family[0] = k;
    }
    for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
      for(j=0;j<nints;j++) {
        if(family[i] % ints[j] == 0) {
          if(!icontains(flags, l+1, ints[j])) {
            flags[l++] = ints[j];
            if(l>=nints) goto done;
          }
          continue;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  done:
  fprintf(stdout,"%d\n",k);
  free(family);
  free(ints);
  free(flags);
}

void swap(char *x, char *y) {
  char temp;
  temp = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = temp;
}

int icontains(int *array, int len, int a) {
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
    if(array[i]==a) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

void permute(unsigned int **result, char *a, int l, int r, int *len) {
  static int buflen = 10;
  int *new_result;
  int i, aint;
  if(l == 0) *len = 0;
  if(l == r) {
    if(a[0] == '0') return;
    aint = atoi(a);
    if(*len > buflen) {
      buflen = (int)(((float)*len)*1.5f);
      new_result = realloc(*result, buflen * sizeof(*result));
      if(new_result != NULL) {
        *result = new_result;
      }else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't allocate memory for buffer.");
      }
    }
    (*result)[(*len)++] = aint;
  }else {
    for(i=l;i<=r;i++) {
      swap((a+l), (a+i));
      permute(result, a, l+1, r, len);
      swap((a+l), (a+i)); //backtrack
    }
  }
}

)
```

Comment: Perhaps the latest version as a separate post?  Any ideas applied to that take away from the answers to the earlier versions.

Comment: @chux [Here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/108074/optimize-program-to-test-for-divisibility-of-numbers-3-0) is the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

- **Performance**

  It is very slow because you build all permutations. It is unnecessary. You need just one, that which has digits in the increasing order (careful with leading 0).
- **Algorithm**

  Please disregard. I misread the problem statement.

  <s>Compute *a minimal* number which is divisible by the arguments. Convert it to string. Sort the string in ascending order. Take care of leading zeroes, if any.</s>

  Keep in mind that there might be other numbers (at most 8) with the same property. Check them all, as long as they have the same number of digits.
- **Code**

  `main` is massive and must be refactored into more functions doing clearly defined jobs.

  `factorial` will break at about `n == 13` with integer overflow.

Comment: @JS1 One of us is misreading the problem statement. I understand that there must be a permutation divisible by the entire set. You understand (correct me if I am wrong) that each number in a set must divide at least one permutation.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but I don't really understand what you mean "You need just one...", could you perhaps show me an example? :)

Answer (score 2):

## Bug

You write to `flags`, but you never allocate any space for it.  If you had turned on full compiler warnings, it would have warned you about that.

## Use ints, not strings

Part of the reason your program is so slow is that you keep all of your values in strings instead of ints.  Then you use `atoi()` to convert the same strings over and over.  Just convert your numbers once and then keep them in `int` format for later reuse.

## Massive allocations

Your program also allocates one string per permutation (i.e. the `family` array).  You never use the old permutations, so you should just have one permutation buffer and overwrite it instead of allocating new buffers all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, regarding the bug I accidently removed that line of code because it was wrong and never put it back, but I fixed it now :)